# Editing core magento files doesn't update

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am editing core Magento file to get a more specific error message. But when I update the file it still acts like the old file is in existence with the old code. I've tried flushing all caches, removing cache folder.

Is there something else I need to do?

Magento 1.9.3.7

Comment: Maybe this class is overriden already?

Comment: That could be possible, is there a place to see if it is overwritten and with which file?

Comment: Try use IDE search in project option with phraze `extends your_class`. Btw. IDE should mark you near class name that class is extended and can point you to this class.

Comment: Thanks found it!

Comment: Why did nobody mention that modifying core magento files is a terrible practice? You should at least create a copy of the file you're trying to modify in the [local folder](https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/m1wiki/pages/14024897/How+to+Create+a+Local+Copy+of+app+code+core+Mage), if not create a new module and rewrite it properly.

Comment: Of course I only edited it temporarily to check something about, but good call either way.